# Troubleshooting: Cookies Added on C# side but not in Browser

Tags: c#, angular, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

```
public void AddCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue, CookieOptions options)
{
    string baseAddress = "localhost";
    cookieContainer.Add(new System.Net.Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue,"/",baseAddress));
}
                                                                                                                                             [HttpPost("login")]
public ActionResult Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
{
    var userToLogin = _authService.Login(userForLoginDto);
    if (!userToLogin.Success)
    {
        return BadRequest(userToLogin.Massage);
    }

    var result = _authService.CreateAccessToken(userToLogin.Data);

    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
    {
        Domain = "localhost",
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = true,
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict
    };
    _cookie.AddCookie("auth-token", result.Data.Token, cookieOptions);
    _cookie.PrintCookies();
    if (result.Success)
    {
        return Ok(result);
    }

    return BadRequest(result.Massage);
}

public void PrintCookies()
{
    foreach (System.Net.Cookie cookie in cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost:4200/%22")))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": " + cookie.Value);
    }
}
```

I would like to add browser cookies, but they are not being added. While I am typing PrintCookies in the console, it appears that the cookies have been added on the c# side, but the browser doesn't come up either.

Please help, I cannot disable cookies in the browser.